# How can I programatically configure a virtual directory to require SSL using IIS 6?

Tags: ssl, iis-6, certificate, configure

How can I programatically configure a virtual directory on IIS 6 to require SSL and client certificates from a starting point of having a suitable certificate already in the local certificate store, but, the current website (e.g. Default Web Site) having not been set up to use certificates?

I know how to do this using the inetmgr GUI, but, I would like to be able to perform these actions programatically, preferably from a batch script or a C# program.

I have come across IISCertDeploy.vbs from the IIS 6.0 Resource Kit, but, I don't think it meets my needs.  If this can be used then I would appreciate a more helpful example of how to use it than it provides.

**Update: I have managed to find a solution which works as long as the Default Web Site has an SSL certificate installed.  Here is an explanation of my solution for anyone who has a similar problem.**

I have written a batch script (included below) which uses [Microsoft's adsutil.vbs](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true).  I have not managed to programatically install the certificate against the defualt website yet, but, having that as a manual one-off step is acceptable for now.

```
@echo off

if [%1]==[] GOTO NOPARAM

echo Setting SSL requirements for virtual directory '%1' 

REM Setting: Require Secure Channel (SSL) = true
adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/root/%1/AccessSSL true

REM Setting: Require client certificates = true
adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/root/%1/AccessSSLNegotiateCert true

REM Set required SSL file permission flags
REM  (104 -> AccessSSL=8 | AccessSSLNegotiateCert=32 | AccessSSLRequireCert=64)
adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/root/%1/AccessSSLFlags 104
GOTO END


:NOPARAM
REM Exit if no virtual directory was specified.
echo Error: Expected parameter specifying virtual directory was not defined.
GOTO END

:END
```